# Filter the swagger endpoints using tags when using drf_yasg in Django

Tags: python, django, swagger-ui, drf-yasg

When I generate the swagger ui using the default schema provided by [documentation](https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/readme.html#quickstart), it generates both `api`, `api2` endpoints.I want to get only the `api` endpoints. I tried overriding the get_schema method as below but didn't work.

```
class CustomOpenAPISchemaGenerator(OpenAPISchemaGenerator):
    def get_schema(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Generate a :class:`.Swagger` object with custom tags"""
        schema = super().get_schema(*args, **kwargs)
        schema.tags = [
            {
               "name":"api"
            }
        ]
        return schema

schema_view = get_schema_view(
   openapi.Info(
      title="API docs",
      default_version='v1',
      description="REST API",
   ),
   generator_class=CustomOpenAPISchemaGenerator,
   public=True,
   permission_classes=[permissions.AllowAny],
)
```

Can someone give me a solution to get only the endpoints with tag of `api`?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it didn't work"? What are you expecting and what are you getting? Please be specific. Did you get errors? If so, then please share them.